# How do I count and block an Observable executing on another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a base RxJava 2 `Observable` which I am running on the main thread. I am then calling `observeOn` to run some computation on another thread. I'm then using `autoConnect` to subscribe a `count` and another side-effecting operation (writing out the results of the computation). In the example this is shown as `System.out.println`, but pretend this is an operation that could take a while. I want to avoid a possible race condition where the count finishes, but writing out the results of the last element of the computation on the other thread does not complete.

To do this, I have created a `Future` from the `.count()` call, called a `blockingSubscribe` on the side-effecting operation, and finally called `.get()` on the future, to ensure that the main thread blocks on the completion of both observable operations. Is there a better solution here to avoid losing out on writing the last element? Do I even need to do this or is there some guarantee Observables give that I am missing?

It is also worth noting that I want to avoid repeating the computation of the initial elements of the Observable, as this may happen after many expensive steps.

My sample code is shown below.

```
Stream<Integer> ints = ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
    .stream().map(i -> {
      System.out.println("emitting:" + i);
      return i;
    });

Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.fromIterable(() -> ints.iterator())
    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    .map(x -> x + 1)
    .publish()
    .autoConnect(2);

Future<Long> count = observable.count().toFuture();
// pretend that instead of printing here, this operation
// could take some time to complete
observable.blockingSubscribe(i -> System.out.println("got " + i));
Long c = count.get();

return count;
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of creating 2 streams you can do all the work at single stream:

```
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.fromIterable(() -> ints.iterator())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .map(x -> x + 1);

observable.doOnNext(integer -> {
    //your heavy work here
})
        .count()
        .subscribe(aLong -> {
            //do something with the final count
        });
```

use the side-effect `doOnNext()` to do the heavy computation, and in the subscribe after `count()` operator, do something with the final count.
this will guarantee you order of execution, notifications will never occur simultaneously, this is part of Observable contract, do each `doOnNext()` will happen serially, by the same reasons, the final `onNext()` at the subscriber, will happen last, as `count()` operator is based on completion of source `Observable` (`onComplete` notification) and thus will happen after all items were emitted and processed at `doOnNext()`.

Comment: Is there another way to do this though? I thought about basically adding another map call with a side effect, which is essentially what this is doing, but if I had many things I wanted to subscribe off of the first observable this would become cumbersome quickly, and it doesn't feel like the best design in my opinion.

Comment: what do you mean another map call? where? well, this is just a suggestion, the point is that you can have a single stream, you can also have 2 streams,  you can need replay() the observable and use concat() to ensure sequential execution. but in either way, I think that using blocking stream is less than ideal.

Comment: as for best design, it is very depends on what the real work done here, is the heavy work related to the count? is the source observable related to both? do you need an Observable with some output? anyhow even with single stream you can split it and add compose the logic in different parts of the app